# Transition to another page Phonegap iPhone

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I am new to phone gap development,how to do page transition in phone gap using the jQuery.I used this $.mobile.changePage( "activity.html", { transition: "slideup"}); for transition ,but its not working.Can anyone point me in right direction how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hii am also facing transition issue plz help me if u solve this. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`jQuery` basically represents pages using `divs` inside a single `.html` file. And changePage uses the jQuery Mobile AJAX functionality, If you really want to navigate to some other, you can use basic `javascript`.

```
window.location.href="your-new-page.html";
```

or

```
$.mobile.changePage( "second-page.html", { transition: "slideup"});
```

To navigate pages created using div you can use

```
$.mobile.changePage( "#pageHome", { transition: "slideup"});
```

`#pageHome`  - id of the page div.

You could refer the following links too

[Link 1](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/mobile-changepage-and-rel-external)

[Link 2](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/widgets/pages/)

I Hope it helps.

Comment: You can use changePage to navigate to other html page too. But it will only load the first div. You can make the link with rel="external" so that it opens a new page.

Answer (score 0):

That is jQuery mobile. You need to include both jquery and jquery mobile javascript to make it work.

Don't forget to include the corresponding jquery mobile css too!

Look at the example in the docs if you need further reference.

Example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response,I have included everything,my problem is in transition,when tap on button next screen comes and fade.Any solution for this,am developing iPhone phone gap application.